# How to handle less input than expected with scanf - C

Tags: c, input, scanf

I need to receive from the user input that can come in 2 forms, `char` `int` `float` or `char` `int`, but I don't know which of them will be given. I tried this:

```
int main(){
    char letter;
    int num;
    float value;
    while(getchar()!=EOF){
        scanf(" %c %d %f", &letter, &num, &value);
        printf("%c\n", letter);
        printf("%d\n", num);
        printf("%f\n", value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this is when I give an input like this:

```
? 12345
g 12345 45.6
? 12345

Output given:                      Expected Output:
1                                  ?
2345                               12345
0.000000                           0.000000
1                                  g
2345                               12345
45.599998                          45.599998
?                                  ?
12345                              12345
45.599998                          45.599998
```

Why is part of the number going in the place of the `char` and the `char` is ignored? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I think what's happening is that you are accidently reading the first char using `getchar()!=EOF`.

Comment: And would there be away to avoid this? I need to stop the program using the ctrl+d comaand that´s why it is there.

Comment: Your main loop should be along the lines of `int numvals; while ((numvals = scanf("…", …)) >= 2) { … }`.  The loop will only continue while you manage to convert 2 or 3 values.  You should always check the return value from functions like `scanf()`; ignoring it is a bug.

Comment: Well yes - you've got great answers from other people.

Comment: The error was in fact the getchar()!=EOF, using Jonathan Leffer sugestion it got fixed, if any of you would want to give it as  the answer i would mark it as correct, thanks to both.

Comment: Doesn´t seem fair, since they came up with the answer not me.

Comment: Have you tried to `ungetc` the value of `getchar()` before `scanf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. The missing char. When you do `while(getchar()!=EOF)` for the first time, you are consuming the first character in the stream, which happens to be `'?'`. The subsequent `scanf()` cannot retrieve that anymore, so it grabs the next non-whitespace character, which happens to be the `'1'` of the following number.

   After that `'1'` is read, the rest of the number is parsed, providing the result `2345`.

   The following conversion tries to parse a float, but the next non-whitespace character is a `g`, so no float can be read, and the conversion fails.
2. You fail to check, how many conversions are successful. `scanf()` dutifully returns the number of successful conversions, but you ignore that.

   If you had checked the return value, you would have found that the first `scanf()` call returns `2` because the character and the integer conversions finished successfully, but the float conversion failed.

   Likewise, the second `scanf()` call should have returned `3`, signaling that all three conversions succeeded. The last call to `scanf()` should return `2` again.
3. The gobbling up of a character in `while(getchar()!=EOF)` bites you again on the second line, this time it is the `'g'` that's removed from the stream before the `scanf()` gets a chance to read it.

   After the second call to `scanf()` successfully terminates, the `'\n'` character is left in the stream. Thus, the following `while(getchar()!=EOF)` gobbles that up, and the third `scanf()` call can finally correctly fetch the first character on the line (`'?'`).
4. The float conversion fails again on the third input line, and the corresponding variable is left untouched, and you fail to detect this condition by ignoring the return value of `scanf()`.

Long story short:

- Each `getchar()` call consumes a character that cannot be read by `scanf()` anymore.
- Any `scanf()` call that ignores the return value is a bug. Without checking that, you cannot know that you actually read anything.

---

Btw: `man scanf` and `man getchar` could have told you everything I just said. It pays off to know how to read manpages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as i said before, the problem was already solved in the comments. Anyway i will mark your answer as the correct one since the people who solved the problem first dont seem to want to claim it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's best to first retrieve the user input as char* (fgets-like) and then parse it with sscanf (not scanf, sscanf).
You will have to check the return value of sscanf in order to know wether the input user is correctly formatted.

If you need to check if there is not garbage value after the parsing (like "g 12345 45.6 garbagevalue"), you can add a %c after and check if the value have changed.

```
char   letter;
int    integerNumber;
double floatingNumber;
char   end;
char *userInput = ...;

end = '\0';
if (sscanf(userInput, "%c %d %f%c", &letter, &integerNumber, &floatingNumber, &end) == 3 && end == '\0') {
    // First form
} else {
    end = '\0';
    if (sscanf(userInput, "%c %d%c", &letter, &integerNumber, &end) == 2 && end == '\0') {
        // Second form
    } else {
        // Error : Input not strictly "%c %d %f" or "%c %d"
    }
}
```

Sound good to you ?

Comment: Just in case you didn't know: [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) returns the number of successfully read items, so in this case it must return 3 or 2 for valid values.

Comment: I just dont get one thing, what is "char *userInput = ...;" supposed to equal?

Comment: @MiguelID : I will not do all the code for you. I've merely give you some way to do what you want with scanf family. It's up to you to replace the "..." part with the revelant code in your situation.

Comment: @Yonlif Yeah I know, but the code is an example if you want to have strictly "%c %d %f" without garbage value in the user input string after %f or %d. Futhermore, what happen if the user input string is "integer float" ? The return is still 2, which by your way is "correct", but there should be 3 results, which is in final, "incorrect". Depending your case, you can end up with a really restrictive scanf format like "%c[ ]%d[ ]%f%c" in order to ensure that what you parse is exactly what you expect.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry this comment wasn't directed to you but to the author of the question. Just for his information...

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it would be simpler to read in a block of data from the keyboard to a string from the keyboard and then analyse with `sscanf` as in the outline below

```
#define MAX_INPUT 100

char data_input[MAX_INPUT];
int finished=0, test;

char letter;
int num;
float value;

while (finished==0) {
  // scanf("%s",data_input); //taken out after useful comments below
  fgets(data_input,100,stdin);  //replacement from comments...

  // insert code using sscanf to read in data from user
  test=sscanf(data_input, "%c %d %f", &letter, &num, &value);

  if (test==3) 
  {
    //success - sscanf successfully assigned 3 values... 

    // (ony if you have everything you need then....)
      finished =1; 
  } else if (test==2){
     // insert something to try to test if data from two data entries is ok....

    // (ony if you have everything you need then....)
      finished =1; 
  } else {
    printf("problem with data entry - please type again\n");
  }
}
```

with apologies to @Tom's because the use of `sscanf` was first suggested by him...

Comment: thanks for the answer, but as said in the comments above, the solution from Jonathan Leffler and Yonlif was enought to solve the problem i had.

Comment: And more critical, can lead to buffer overflow. At minimum, it should be "%99s" (or "%.99s" ? I forgot).